# paypal rest api update payment's item

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

i use paypal rest api payments resource to update a payment's amount and item info; i just want change the item's price and tax; and shipping amount; but return MALFORMED_REQUEST; make me drunken...

the request_data is :

```html
 {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/transactions/0/item_list/items/0",
    "value": {
      "name": "hello",
      "quantity": "2",
      "price": "100",
      "currency": "USD",
      "tax": "12"
    }
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/transactions/0/amount",
    "value": {
      "currency": "USD",
      "total": "224",
      "details": {
        "shipping": "12",
        "subtotal": "200",
        "tax": "12"
      }
    }
  }
```

and return :
    {"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"78c05f9b4f21"}

i want make sure that:
1、can update payment's item info with paypal
2、is the path "/transactions/0/item_list/items/0" right
thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I'm using PayPal Java SDK and I used the code below to update the cart items and total value.

```
APIContext context = new APIContext(clientId,clientSecret,environment);

List<Patch> patches = new ArrayList<Patch>();

Amount amount = new Amount();
amount.setCurrency("BRL");
amount.setTotal("100.00");

Patch patch1 = new Patch();
patch1.setOp("replace").setPath("/transactions/0/amount").setValue(amount);

patches.add(patch1);

ItemList items = getItens(order);

Patch patch2 = new Patch();
        patch2.setOp("replace").setPath("/transactions/0/item_list").setValue(items);

patches.add(patch2);

try {

    Payment payment = Payment.get(context, id);

    payment.update(context, patches);

    ...
} ....
```